# Hardrive test using Gsmartcontrol

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

Few weeks ago, my laptop hanged all of a sudden while transferring files from an external harddisk. After i restarted, there was a black screen which showed insert boot device. I checked the boot order and it was fine with my internal harddisk as my primary boot device. I booted from a live linux usb stick and it is working fine and i am able to access my harddrive and all files on it. Previously i had windows 7 running on it but now i did a complete install of linux ubuntu into the harddisk but still the laptop is not booting from it. It only works with the live usb stick. I did a harddrive test using gsmartcontrol software and i have attached a screen shot of the results. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my harddrive?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [hard drive is damaged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes). Backup as much data as possible and replace it.

**Reallocated Sectors Count:**

> Count of reallocated sectors. When the hard drive finds a read/write/verification error, it 
>   **marks that sector as "reallocated" and transfers data to a special
>   reserved area (spare area).** This process is also known as remapping,
>   and reallocated sectors are called "remaps". The raw value normally
>   represents a count of the bad sectors that have been found and
>   remapped. Thus, **the higher the attribute value, the more sectors the
>   drive has had to reallocate. This allows a drive with bad sectors to
>   continue operation; however, a drive which has had any reallocations
>   at all is significantly more likely to fail in the near future.**
>   While primarily used as a metric of the life expectancy of the drive,
>   this number also affects performance. As the count of reallocated
>   sectors increases, the read/write speed tends to become worse because
>   the drive head is forced to seek to the reserved area whenever a remap
>   is accessed. If sequential access speed is critical, the remapped
>   sectors can be manually marked as bad blocks in the file system in
>   order to prevent their use.